# R grid arrange tiff microscopy RGB

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgb, tiff, gridextra

I have a RGB tiff files (from cellProfiler) which I want to import to R, label and arrange - as part of a high throughput analysis. The closest I get is using:

```
library(tiff) 
library(raster)
imageTiff <- tiff::readTIFF(imagePath[i])
rasterTiff <- raster::as.raster(imageTiff)
raster::plot(rasterTiff)
```

raster::plot plots the image nicely but I can't catch the output and use it with gridExtra or add labels.

In addition I tried rasterVis with levelPlot and multiple other ways importing the tiff and then converting them to grob or ggplots.

However, I can't get anything to work and would like to ask if R is even suited at all for that task?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think that is the most straight forward way and possible also the most obvious one.

I import JPEG or TIFF files with jpeg::readJPEG or tiff::readTIFF respectively. Both transform the images to a raster format which is compatible with rasterGrid() and following grid.arrange etc.

```
library(jpeg)
library(tiff)
library(grid)
imageJPEG <- grid::rasterGrob(jpeg::readJPEG("test.jpeg"))
imageTIFF <- grid::rasterGrob(tiff::readTIFF("test.tiff"))

grid.arrange(imageJPEG , imageJPEG , imageJPEG)
grid.arrange(imageTIFF , imageTIFF, imageTIFF)
```

For my purpose that is perfect since tasterGrob does not alter the raster matrix values. Labeling might be a bit tricky but overall it is a grid/grob problem from here on.